# Quick Sort Algorithm: I keep getting a different answer

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to study various sorting and searching algorithms for an upcoming test this Tuesday. All went well until I got to the Quick Sort Algorithm. I did not have a book or any other resource, so I went online and started reading the [SparkNote](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/sorting/quick/summary.html). I thought I understood the text, and I even read the Quick Sort Algorithm part of a [PowerPoint](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ddd/cis3020/summer-97/lectures/lec17) I found online.

However, SparkNote provided an example on the page of the step-by-step process of the algorithm, but it did not show the steps to initially arrange the list. The list given was `[5 9 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 0]`. According to SparkNotes, the arranged list, with the values less than the pivot (which is 5) on the left and the values greater than the pivot on the right, is  `[0 3 4 2 1 5 8 6 7 9]`. However, when I try to go through the steps myself, I keep getting `[ 4 0 3 1 2 5 6 8 7 9 ]`.

The procedure I took was:

```
5 9 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 0 // The initial list. Pivot = 5
5 0 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 9 // Switched 0 and 9.
5 0 3 1 6 4 2 1 7 9 // Switched 8 and 1
5 0 3 1 2 4 6 8 7 9 // Switched 6 and 2
4 0 3 1 2 5 6 8 7 9 // Switched 4 and 5 because the lines that point to the 
                    // greater and smaller numbers crossed.
```

Where is my mistake? Also, I see that the numbers less than 5 are on the left and the numbers greater than 5 are on the right, so, does my mistake really affect the sorting?

Comment: There are many different ways to partition the array for Quick Sort. Just Google "quicksort partition" and you'll find multiple examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm described in SparkNotes initially places the pivot element to the *rightmost* position in the array. The algorithm you used placed/kept the pivot to the *leftmost* position. No wonder the arrangements after partitioning are different.

That means that they started with

```
5 9 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 0
```

chose `5` as pivot and placed it in the rightmost position (exchanged `5` and `0`)

```
0 9 3 8 6 4 2 1 7 5
```

and only after that they performed partitioning for the remaining elements.

You kept your `5` in the leftmost position (apparently you simply forgot to do step 2 from SparkNotes). In the end, both variants work, i.e. there's no "mistake". In your case the arrangement is perfectly valid with the array correctly partitioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8) you can see visual implementation of [Quick-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8) algorithm.

And maybe you will also find useful:

- [Merge-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo)
- [Shell-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmPA7zE8mx0)
- [Bubble-sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4)

**Do not go to links if you hate Hungarian folk dance. :)**

Answer (score 0):

You did not follow the exact algorithm as presented on sparknotes site. Their step two requires you to swap the pivot with the last element.

In any case it is a irrelevant to the algorithm how you exactly perform the partitioning, as long as you split the sequence such that all elements before the pivot are smaller (or equal) to the pivot and the ones that follow it are larger (or equal). When you recursively sort the resulting partitions you'll eventually end up with a sorted sequence.

It's a matter of efficiency, not correctness, how you handle equal elements and how you choose the pivot, as well as at what sequence length you eventually switch to another algorithm.